# Spring-Hibernate Error: Error loading class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean]

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am trying a sample application which uses Spring-Hibernate integration. However I am getting this error when I load config.xml

`Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in class path resource [SpringDAO/config.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/support/PersistenceExceptionTranslator`

Here's my config.xml code

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="JdbcDAO" class="SpringDAO.JdbcDAO"/>
    <bean id="HibernateDAO" class="SpringDAO.Hibernate"/>

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>SpringDAO/HibernateDAO/SocketStreamedData.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="mySessionFactory"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="socketStreamedDataDAO">
        <property name="hibernateTemplate">
            <ref bean="hibernateTemplate"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Maybe there's something wrong with `mappingResources` property class is incorrect or something. However, what I have specified there is full classpath for that hibernate xml config. So what could be the problem? Please help me.

Comment: Check your classpath. You need Spring Transaction (spring-tx). Is the JAR present?

Comment: ohhh I will check that

Comment: yep that it was...however now I get another. `Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in class path resource [SpringDAO/config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider`

Comment: Check your classpath again. Is Hibernate present?

Comment: yes indeed !! :D I then included caching related jars. Then another error came that javax.persistence. some class I dont remember now, is missing. However, my original issue is solved. If you could please enter your solution in answer, I can select it as answer, you get your reward and I can close this question. As I now see many more errors are to come. I can't just keep on asking every. However, I sincerely thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source of a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` is most of time a problem in classpath. Here you have to check that Spring TX and Hibernate are present in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Please add spring tx jar in your class path.I faced the same issue and solved by adding the spring-tx jar.

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem